# Skip library function in arm assembly GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm

I need to debug this part of arm assembly code,

```
for3:
ldrb r3,[r4,#0]
ldr r0,=format2
mov r1,r3
bl printf
add r4,r4,#1
cmp r3,#'\0'
bne for3
```

It contain a `printf` statement from c, when I debug it goes trough `printf` code for hundreds of lines. I need to skip external library functions and go through only my code. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `finish` command in GDB to have the application continue until it returns from the current stack frame. (It can be abbreviated as `fin`.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ni` (`nexti`) instead of `si` to [step over function calls](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html):

> `nexti`
>   `nexti arg`
>   `ni`
>
> Execute one machine instruction, but if it is a
>   function call, proceed until the function returns. 
>   An argument is a repeat count, as in `next`.

Comment: It seems like this doesn't go through the entire function, I had to give the command several times to go until the return..

Comment: Most likely you need extra *.debug* info in the assembler for this to work.  For instance, `.type foo3, %function;` and, `.sizeof foo3, . - foo3;` and, `.fnend`, etc.  This would work with straight **C** code or appropriately annotated assembler.

Comment: @Madushan: you should use it *before* you enter `printf`, i.e. after the `mov r1,r3` (or you can just use `ni` instead of `si` all the time).

Answer (score 2):

While finish does the trick (once you entered the function), if you need to do this repeatedly, also look into gdb's [skip](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html) command.